# MySql query returning me undesired results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table like follows:

```
      id                      some attribute
1196670907478919031,fb39f78853bfe42279a8f56bc5671eb9,.....
4915018864030990478,44ecf841a778525b925023321761e458, ........
3161434036923224050,2fd54178a92a4b1a83643d9faa1fec9e,......
```

Now i have my friendedges table as follows

```
      a                          b               status
 '4915018864030990478', '3161434036923224050', 'accepted'
 '4915018864030990478', '1196670907478919031', 'accepted'
```

To get all the friends of user with id=4915018864030990478 i wrote the following query but i am getting the following result
 Query

```
select id, firstName, lastName, gender, pictureSet  FROM  Member m JOIN  friendedges f ON f.a = m.id where a = "4915018864030990478";
```

Results

```
 '4915018864030990478', 'sdsds', 'dsd', 'M', '1'
 '4915018864030990478', 'sdsds', 'dsd', 'M', '1'
```

Where i must get the friend ids. And i don't know why it generated duplicated result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is this :

```
select f.id, f.firstName, f.lastName, f.gender, f.pictureSet
FROM Member m
JOIN friendedges e ON e.a = m.id
JOIN Member f ON e.b = f.id
where e.a = "4915018864030990478";
```

or more simply (if you need no data from your member) :

```
select id, firstName, lastName, gender, pictureSet
FROM  Member m JOIN  friendedges f ON f.b = m.id
where a = "4915018864030990478";
```

In the second query, I just changed `f.a` to `f.b`.

Comment: well id, firstName . lastname ...belong to Member table and not friendedges table

Comment: Is this not possible with one join

Comment: Yes now second one looks okay.Thanks Dystroy

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates:

```
select DISTINCT f.b, firstName, lastName, gender, pictureSet  
FROM  Member m
JOIN  friendedges f ON f.a = m.id 
where f.a = "4915018864030990478";
```

Comment: Well distinct is not a problem. The problem is I am not gettting the friends..I am getting the user again